# excel: 4 different pay scales at work w/ running tally of each value including swap from "base hours" to Overtime

Tags: excel

Here's a challenge for you! We have 4 different pay scales at work (billable, non-billable, billable o.t., and non-billable o.t.). I have a 14 day "daily hours sheet" in excel and need to have running tally of these 4 values per day inclusive of when they swap over into overtime hours. E.g. an employee might work 7 billable hours and have 3 non-billable hours on monday, tuesday 2 billable hours and 9 non-billable hours, etc. once 40 hours is reached of these 2 combined values, they go into the next two pay scales (billable o.t., non-billable o.t.). I need a formula to show these 4 values and reflect accurately when they swap over into the two overtime values. The way I presently have it is wrong and tallys the billable hours up to 40 hours (of the week total) and counts everything after that whether billable or not as billable overtime and same for non billable hours. With the combination of "base" billable and non billable hours, a person might reach their 40 hours on say Thursday, and I don't have a way of adjusting hours for the remainder of the week whether billable or non billable into the respective overtime scale for those hours(billable o.t. or non-billable). I humbly request the help of minds greater than mine.

Comment: The table I have set up reading from left to right clmn values are as follows: Date, Time in, Lunch start, lunch end, time out, total hours worked, billable hours, non-billable hours. The total hours worked auto populates that days value less time for lunch with the equation I have based on punch in punch out values, but I have to manually fill in how many of those total hours were billbalble and non-billable. on the bottom of the table i have a =sum total that tells me the weeks total hours worked, total billable, and total non billable but I dont have a way of distinguishing O.t. hours.

Comment: Is there an equation that shows: for the week there were (say) 30 billable pay rate hours, 10 non- billable pay rate hours, 42 billable O.T. rate hours and 7 non-billable O.T. rate hours? That make more sense of what I'm trying to achieve haha? I know its kind of hard to explain in one swoop above. But thats my end goal- to find out those 4 total values for the week, multiply them by their respective pay grades, and have it auto transfer billable and non billable hours totals to the repective O.t. pay grade columns for the remainder of that week once 40 hours has been reached.

Comment: Both billable and nonbillable hours being cumlative, a person may for example, have 30 billable hours and 9 nonbillable hours by 3pm wednesday then at 4pm wednesday they happen to be doing non billable work for an additional 2 hours (now nonbillable O.t.). Thursday they clock in another 8 billable hours (now in o.t.) and 2 nonbillable O.t. hours and so on for the rest of the week. I need 4 columns that show the cumlative total each day throughout the week showing "total billable hrs x pay", "total nonbillable hours x pay", "total billable o.t. hrs x pay", "total nonbillable ot hrs x pay" (x=*)

Answer (score 0):

In order to give a better answer we will need more details of the data that you have to work with. It sounds like a =sumif() or combination of =if(sumif()>40) will work for you though.

Lets say you have an Hours, Type, and Overtime Column. In the hours, its the hours worked, in the type it is either billable, or non-billable. The Overtime column is the calculation column.

Then if you use a formula like this, it will say overtime or regular:

```
=IF(SUMIF($B$2:B2,"Billable",$A$2:A2)>40,"Overtime","Regular")
```

Then at the bottom, you could have a few =sumproduct() formulas to tabulate the amounts of each. Ie:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A10*(B2:B10="Billable")*(C2:C10="Regular"))
```

This sums A2 to A10 if they are Billable, and Regular time. (Otherwise those conditions would return 0)

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Above sol. won't work though-doesn't compute correctly for my purposes as both billable and non billable hours added together are cumulative for the week. Made simple blank excel sheet exactly as you proposed to test out before integrating into my sheet I found a flaw- for column A2:A8 put in values respectively 10,20,15,20,20,10,10. In "type column" B2:B8 respectively: billable, billable, billable, non-billable, non-billable, billable, non-billable. Yields: reg billable hrs- 30, reg non-bill hrs- 0, billable o.t.-25, non-bill o.t.-50. See? Where's rem. 10 reg billable